# The sign of zero with floats

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Consider the following code performing operations on complex numbers with C/C++'s `float`:

```
float real_part = log(3.f);
float imag_part = 0.f;

float real_part2 = (imag_part)*(imag_part)-(real_part*real_part);
float imag_part2 = (imag_part)*(real_part)+(real_part*imag_part);
```

The result will be

```
real_part2= -1.20695 imag_part2= 0
angle= 3.14159
```

where `angle` is the phase of the complex number and, in this case, is `pi`.

Now consider the following code:

```
float real_part = log(3.f);
float imag_part = 0.f;

float real_part2 = (-imag_part)*(-imag_part)-(real_part)*(real_part);
float imag_part2 = (-imag_part)*(real_part)+(real_part)*(-imag_part);
```

The result will be

```
real_part2= -1.20695 imag_part2= 0
angle= -3.14159
```

The imaginary part of the result is `-0` which makes the phase of the result be `-pi`.

Although still accomplishing with the principal argument of a complex number and with the signed property of floating point's `0`, this changes is a problem when one is defining functions of complex numbers. For example, if one is defining `sqrt` of a complex number by the de Moivre formula, this will change the sign of the imaginary part of the result to a wrong value.

How to deal with this effect?

Comment: In `float imag_part2 = (-imag_part)*(real_part) ...` there is a `-`.  In `complex_number3b.y=complex_number3a.x*complex_number3a.y ...` there is no `-`.  Is this your intent?

Comment: @chux `imag_part` is changed in sign in both the cases. When calculating `imag_part2`, I'm changing the sign of `imag_part`, as you noticed. When calculating `complex_number3b`, the sign change is within `complex_number3a.x` which is equal to `-imag_part`.

Comment: There is no minus sign in `…+(real_part*imag_part)`.

Comment: @chux I apologize. You were right. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: now that the question appears to make sense, it seems like the kind of question that Kahan answers when he writes, in his article [Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions](http://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf):

> Generally, mixed-mode arithmetic combining real and complex variables should be performed directly, not by first coercing the real to complex, lest the sign of zero be rendered uninformative; the same goes for combinations of pure imaginary quantities with complex variables. And doing arithmetic directly this way saves execution time that would otherwise be squandered manipulating zeros.

In other words, even the principal designer of the IEEE 754 standard does not know how to make the sign of zero make sense when computing on complex numbers, some of which have been promoted from reals.

---

Answering the initial question:

I do not see anything wrong in the computations you show.

```
float imag_part = 0.f;

float imag_part2 = (-imag_part)*(real_part)+(real_part*imag_part);
```

This sets `imag_part2` to `-0. + 0.`, which is `+0.` in round-to-nearest.

```
complex_number3b.y=complex_number3a.x*complex_number3a.y+complex_number3a.y*complex_number3a.x;
```

This evaluates to `-0. + -0.`, which itself evaluates to `-0.`.

Your two computations are not equivalent, it is normal for them not to produce the same result. Both results are in accordance with [IEEE 754 rules for the sign of zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I'm not claiming there is something wrong. I'm somewhat surprised, as the computations seem totally equivalent. They apparently should perform exactly the same operations, as it can be inferred from literal substitution of `-imag_part` and `real_part` in place of `complex_number3a.x` and `complex_number3a.y`, respectively. But perhaps this is a matter of the _invisible_ behavior of the compiler. My real question at the bottom of the post is on _how dealing with this effect_? Is there a _consistent_ way to deal with complex numbers?

Comment: @JackOLantern You have written `…+(real_part*imag_part)`. Substituting  `complex_number3a.x` with `-imag_part` in `…+complex_number3a.y*complex_number3a.x` does not produce `…+(real_part*imag_part)`. If you do the substitution right, you will get the same result. The way to deal with the effect you describe is to do the substitution right.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. I made some confusion. Please, see my edited post. My problem is that, depending on the sign of `0`, I can have different results when applying de Moivre formula. Is there any standard trick to deal with this?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It clarified me where the problem comes from as well as it suggested possible directions to face it.